# How to avoid multiple calls to a slow function when using scipy integration with complex valued functions?

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, numerical-integration

I'm trying to numerically integrate a 2D complex-valued function multiple times. The problem with the current setup which I have which works fine but it is understandably slow.

The slow part of the below code is `ssht.create_ylm(theta, phi, self.L)` which basically finds the spherical harmonics up to a band-limit `L` for the angles in question (can be arrays rather than floats). At the moment I'm calling `self.f` twice for the real and imaginary parts but this, of course, means that I'm being very inefficient. However, I'm not sure how to about saving intermediate values.

I looked into [quadpy](https://pypi.org/project/quadpy/) which seems to be able to handle complex-valued functions but not sure how to go about this.

The below example is a sub-set of a class:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import pyssht as ssht # user-defined cython code

def f(self, theta, phi, i, j):
    ylm = ssht.create_ylm(theta, phi, self.L)
    ylm = ylm.reshape(ylm.size)
    f = ylm[i] * np.conj(ylm[j]) * np.sin(theta)
    return f

def real_func(self, theta, phi, i, j):
    return self.f(theta, phi, i, j).real

def imag_func(self, theta, phi, i, j):
    return self.f(theta, phi, i, j).imag

def integral(self, f, i, j):
    F = integrate.dblquad(
        f,
        self.phi_min,
        self.phi_max,
        lambda t: self.theta_min,
        lambda t: self.theta_max,
        args=(i, j),
    )[0]
    return F

def D_integral(self, i, j):
    F_real = self.integral(self.real_func, i, j)
    F_imag = self.integral(self.imag_func, i, j)
    return F_real + 1j * F_imag

def D_matrix(self):
    D = np.zeros((self.side.size, self.side.size), dtype=complex)
    for i in range(self.side.size):
        for j in range(i, self.side.size):
            integral = self.D_integral(self.side[i], self.side[j])
            D[i][j] = integral
            if i != j:
                D[j][i] = np.conj(integral)
    return D
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this in a more clever way, and if not at least in a way which avoids the need to call `ssht.create_ylm` twice per one integration step.

Comment: @newkid Their function is inexpensive to call, so they don't mind calling it twice

Comment: What is your domain of integration?

Comment: theta: 0 to pi, phi: 0 to 2pi